# How to Execute js of a webelement in Selenium

Tags: html, vb.net, selenium

On a target Webpage, I have a **HTML Button** elements with following sub-tags (Excess HTML statements removed for brevity)

```
<a class="ebookreader" onclick="getBook2Read('12','Journey of India','Author-JN')">Read</a>
<a class="ebookreader" onclick="getBook2Read('32','Journey of Punjab','Author-JN')">Read</a>
<a class="ebookreader" onclick="getBook2Read('33','Journey of Haryana','Author-JN')">Read</a>
<a class="ebookreader" onclick="getBook2Read('38','Journey of Uttar Pradesh','Author-JN')">Read</a>
```

In my VB 2019 Code using Selenium Driver, I want to execute the **js** code related with `onclick`.

I have tried following statements, but in vain

```
For Each book In driver.FindElementsByClassName("ebookreader")
    book.GetAttribute("onclick")
    book.GetCssValue("onclick")
Next
```

But am not able to move ahead. I even tried creating filling a `ListBox` but the values added in the `ListBox` are shown as `OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement` or `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeWebElement`

Is there a way to invoke onclick js from Selenium?

Comment: You can just click the desired element using selenium click() method and when element is clicked, browser will itself invoke the onclick method. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, 'Journey of India')]")).click() --> clicks 'Journey of India' link

Comment: I tried that but it is not working that way.

Comment: Also, It may trigger to open the page in a new window, thereby losing track of Window Handle

Comment: For Each book In driver.FindElementsByClassName("bookread") --> classname seems incorrect --> should be  'ebookreader'

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
For Each book In driver.FindElementsByClassName("ebookreader")
  Dim onClickValue As String = book.GetAttribute("onclick")
  If onClickValue <> "" Then
     listBooks.Items.Add(onClickValue)
  End If
Next
```

`listBooks` is the VB.Net forms `ListBox Control`